# A lot of trouble with Prettier in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

My prettier extension is completely refusing to work.
I've pretty much tried every solution online, gone through all similar question here and tried all the solutions, including uninstalling and reinstalling Prettier and VS Code itself. I've also cleared a lot of cache as recommended somewhere and nothing changed. Prettier appears enabled and with all the correct settings activated. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: So from the perspective of a person who wants to help you, its really hard to do so because I need more details. Are you using a VSCode extension & if so which one? Did you download the prettier CLI via NPM? Are you using a linter too (like ESLint?). Do you have a prettier configuration file — something like _`.prettierrc`_ )? Are you using any plugins? are you using a compiler like __TSC__, or __Babel__? Was __Prettier__ working previously?

Comment: I am not trying to give you a hard time, I know that often times people can ask for these things in a less-than-polite manner. I just need to know what your environment looks like, and how you are implementing the program that is prettier (extension, node_module, or both. Also any plugins.). Maybe posting your `.prettierrc` file might help too. If you don't have one, copy and past the one from here into your root directory. https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html#basic-configuration - use the JSON option, and add it to a file named .prettierrc (no file extension).

Comment: Also you can try downloading the NPM module via, `$ npm i -DE prettier` when you have prettier configured with some plugins, or use a special prettier extension, having the module can be required.

Comment: @JΛY-ÐΞV Thanks for getting back to me and sorry for responding late.
I'm just using prettier as an extenstion, installed via extensions markedplace.
Using the latest version v9.0.0 I've already tried older versions just in case but same problem. 
Not using a linter or plugins. I don't have a prettier configuration file (as far as I know) and I'm not using a compiler either. Tbh, I haven't been using VS Code for very long and a lot of these terms are new to me.
Prettier was working previously. Had a few hickups sometimes but could always be sorted with re-setting it as default formatter.

Comment: Okay lets uh see if we can diagnose the problem, and try to see if we can come up with a more explicit question, which would require us to solve your issue. The first thing you need to do is add the .prettierrc configuration file to your root directory.  The next thing you are going to want to do is check & make sure you have the official, standard Prettier extension installed. To check that, make sure your extension is the one from this link (you will download it in-editor, but this is the market place link you can use to make sure we both are on the same page about the extension your using)

Comment: Here is the link, I couldn't fit it in the comment above. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode After you do those two things, check that you have the official standard prettier extension, and that you have added the .prettierrc configuration file, with the JSON configuration added to it from the link I posted last week, let me know, there are a couple more steps to troubleshooting the issue. This process is the standard process VSCode developers use, and it works on most extension-issues, so it is good to learn it anyhow.

Comment: @JΛY-ÐΞV Thanks for staying on this with me. I have added a .prettierrc.json file to the root directory of my current project. Or was I meant to add it to the esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.0.0 directory of my VS Code installation?
In the .prettierrc file I saved this code:
```{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 4,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true
}
```
I definitely have the version from your link installed and I've done so in-editor.
Hope I've done everything right so far and thanks again for your help!

Comment: So, when you write code professionally, the style guide you are required to follow can change, in other words; when someone pays a developer to write code, the person dishing out the ***$$$*** gets to decide what the style is, consequently; professional devs have to adhere to different style-guides which often change from project to project. The reason I am telling you this, is so u understand that Every project needs its own ___`".prettierrc"`___ file, and it needs to be in the very first directory you create for your projects (aka your Root Directory).

Comment: Because VSCode is written in the Node.js Runtime. It makes using Node.js a really great option for configuring, testing & troubleshooting your extensions, dev-tools, Modules, plugins, Editor-features, etc... If your writing JS in VSCode, you should already have Node.JS & NPM (Node JavaScript Package Manager) installed, if you don't follow this guide to install them  https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm.

Comment: Once they are installed, create a new Project named ___"Troubleshoot-Prettier"___ , and in test project, add a ___`".prettierrc "`___ file, and a ___`"index.js"`___ file. Leave the  ___`" .prettierrc"`___  file empty. In the ___`" index.js"`___ file, add a line of code that reads: __`"console.log("\n Testing \n\t 1...\n\t 2...\n\t 3... \n")"`__ then save it. Open your console and test run the file via the command  __`~$ node ./index.js`__. It should read the string that is in the `console.log(...)` function call.

Comment: Once you get node working (which is very simple with VSCode, as __VSCode is written in the Node.js RTE__) the rest of the steps should be pretty quick. Im trying to go slow to make sure that if you can't figu re it out anywhere else, then yyou be able to figure it out here. Like I said before, once you see how to do all the little task involved with troubleshooting an extension, you'll actually begin to start looking at extensions, & how the work in a different, more confidant way.

Comment: I followed all your instructions (had npm installed already) and yes, it worked as it should. The command line returned the string from the console.log() function. Does this prove that Node is working? Thanks for going slow, this works well for me.

Comment: Okay great! That's awesome!

Comment: The next thing I would of had you do was go to your settings, and enable "Prettier: Enable Debug Logs" (check it, so that it enables the Prettier debug logs for troubleshooting). Then open the panel that has the terminal in it, but were going to use the VSCode output console, rather than the terminal. Click the output button, to open the output  console (should be next to the word terminal you click on to select terminal). After that go to the drop down, click it so that it'll drop-open its menu, scroll down untill you see Prettier. Select Prettier. Then try to format code, and see what the

Comment: console says. Prettier is on of the most  verbose extension I have troubleshooted in VSCode, but unlike other verbose extensions, __Prettier__'s output is extremely usefull, at producing the important information you need for fixing your Instance of __Prettier__.

Comment: You should probably still do that part because, you would have preformed one of the methods there  is for troubleshooting a VSCode extension. Next time youll know exactly what to do. And please note that this troubleshooting method is not reserved for prettier, it will work for any well developed extension.

Comment: Ok. It all seems to be working according to the output console. As far as I understand. Only two things I'm still unclear about. Will I need to create a .prettierrc file in every project root folder from now on (or maybe only when it's not working)? The other thing is, prettier is still not showing up in the bottom bar of the window. This sounds a bit petty (I'm mainly glad it's working) but it makes me feel like the issue isn't fully resolved yet.

Comment: You want, and you're going to need, your tools working as you expect them to — _in a fully functional state_. That's not petty, that's a completely reasonable thing to want.

Comment: I was having problems formatting JSON with prettier, but it turned out to be a JSON/JSONC issue.

Comment: Okay, so to get __Prettier__ to show up in your Status Bar just right click the Status Bar & select prettier. Then you can fast click that to read __Prettier__ Output any time you need to. Also, make sure you have the `format.onSave` setting configured to true. And yes, you should not only have a .prettierrc file for every project, if you don't want it include with your project, ignore it using a blacklist like _`.gitignore`_.

Comment: You should also read over the documentation at the prettier website that covers the .prettierrc file. Learn what settings are available, and how you should set them. Another tool you might want to consider using in the future is ESLint, which is technically a linter, but it formats as well. Many people use both ESLint & prettier jointly.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you so much, you've been a great help. I thought I was never gonna get prettier back. Can't believe I didn't know about the simple right-click on the status bar. I will look into the prettier documentation and also try to familiarise myself with ESLint. Thanks again for the continued support!

Comment: _I actually enjoy helping people. It helps me learn, and shows me that I have learned. If you ever have any other questions about JS, Node.js, NPM, DOM, VS Code, VS2022, Prettier, Babel, or ESLint, You can always find me on twitter:_  __@JAY_D3V__

Comment: Great! Good to know, thanks for the contact. And glad to hear I didn't wreck your head completely.